# Computing a bounded area via Green's theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm going through some notes regarding finding an area bound in the xy plane.

the Notes say that over a Region R, bounded by a curve C, $$ \iint_{R} dx dy =\oint_{C} \  x dy $$ via Green's Theorem.

No matter how I solve this, I don't see how this is true

I get it to be the following:

$$\iint_{R} 1 \ dx dy = \ \iint_{R} \frac{1}{2} (1-(-1)) \ dx dy \stackrel{\small{Green \ Thm}}{\Large{=}} \ \frac{1}{2}\oint_{C} \  x dy-ydx $$

Is there some change of variables that I'm missing for the y-component?

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think I jus solved it:

$$\iint_{R} 1 \ dx dy = \ \iint_{R} \frac{1}{2} (1-(-1)) \ dx dy \stackrel{\small{Green \ Thm}}{\Large{=}} \ \frac{1}{2}\oint_{C} \  x dy-ydx $$

But also

$$\iint_{R} 1 \ dx dy = \ \iint_{R} (1-(0)) \ dx dy \stackrel{\small{Green \ Thm}}{\Large{=}} \ \oint_{C} \  x dy $$

and

$$\iint_{R} 1 \ dx dy = \ \iint_{R} (0-(-1)) \ dx dy \stackrel{\small{Green \ Thm}}{\Large{=}} \ \oint_{C} \  -ydx $$

Comment: Just depended on which function to choose

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to see that the formula is true is perhaps to view it as a special case of Stokes' Theorem: $\iint_{\Sigma}\nabla\times\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{S}=\oint_{\partial\Sigma}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{\ell}$.

Assume the surface $\Sigma$ is a region in the $xy$-plane bounded by $\partial\Sigma$. The unit normal vector to such a surface is obviously $\mathbf{\hat z}$ and the surface element is just $dS=dxdy$, so $d\mathbf{S}=\mathbf{\hat z}dS=\mathbf{\hat z}dxdy$. To find the area of region $\Sigma$, we just need to find any vector field $\mathbf{F}$ whose curl has $z$ component $1$; any will do.

For $\mathbf{F}=-y\mathbf{\hat x}$, the curl is $\nabla\times\mathbf{F}=1\mathbf{z}$, which is what we're looking for. To get the form of the line integral, take the dot product of $\mathbf{F}$ and $d\mathbf{\ell}=\mathbf{x}dx+\mathbf{y}dy+\mathbf{z}dz$ to arrive at

$$\oint_{\partial\Sigma}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{\ell}=\oint_{\partial\Sigma}(-ydx).$$

Similarly, the curl of $\mathbf{F}=x\mathbf{\hat y}$ is also just $\nabla\times\mathbf{F}=\mathbf{z}$, and we then find the line integral in a simiilar fashion.

The curl of $\mathbf{F}=-y\mathbf{\hat x}+x\mathbf{\hat y}$, however, is $\nabla\times\mathbf{F}=2\mathbf{z}$, so you'll need to divide $\mathbf{F}$ by $2$.